login/su not giving user supplemental groups
I admin several debian (bookworm) machines, with an ldap server which defines users and groups.  A user (defined in ldap) with multiple groups (in ldap) will normally, on login (using ssh) or su, have their primary group and all of the additional groups (as show by "id").  The latest machine we set up only gives the user their main group, not the extras, but otherwise behaves normally.  Users can use "newgrp" to add one of the supplemental groups (and can chain newgrps to add all the ones they'd normally have), so I know the new machine is getting all the group information from ldap.
nsswitch.conf and the various pam.d files are all the same between the new machine and the old ones.  Likewise with ldap.conf, nscd.conf, and nslcd.conf.  I've run nscd -i for passwd and group.
If a user is added to one of the groups in /etc/group, that group will be added on login/su.  It just won't do it for the ldap-defined groups.
Any idea how to fix this?  I'm pretty sure that once upon a time there was a setting to automatically add/not add supplemental groups, but I can't even find a reference to it any more (and I suspect that's not the issue, anyway).
EDIT: And the problem vanished on reboot, so either it was something really random, or one of the things I tried to fix it didn't take effect until the reboot.  And I hardly want to recreate it so I can do more testing. ;)

If you run the command groups ${LOGNAME:-$USER} to ask the system to list all the groups for yourself, does it list the ldap groups or just the local ones? If it lists them all then it is probably a pam issue. If it only lists some then it is probably a name lookup issue.

I would run a tcpdump & see if the system is even communicating with the ldap server.

Given that the problem has vanished without an actual solution, should I just delete the post?
